# How to debug Ionic/Cordova IOS application in Xcode IDE

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Want to debug IOS applications with Xcode, for example, gallery access issue needs to debug for adding an image or video.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/next/#xcode

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Facing the issue with Video upload functionality from the gallery , while uploading video getting issue